# Multiple Buttons on an activity

Tags: button, android-intent

I am new to Java and am trying to figure out how to 
 have four buttons on an activity that add intents to launch to other activities. When I run the code, it stops the application when the emulator gets to this page.

Any help would be sincerely appreciated. Here is my code:

```
package com.helpfinder.app;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;





public class LakeOptions extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lake);

    Button imageButton5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    Button imageButton6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    Button imageButton7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    Button imageButton8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);


   imageButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View imageButton5) {
        Intent goToLakeFood = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeFood.class);
        startActivity(goToLakeFood);

    }
        });
    imageButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View imageButton6) {
       Intent goToLakeHousing = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeHousing.class);
       startActivity(goToLakeHousing);

    }
       });
    imageButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View imageButton7) {
            Intent goToLakeAssistance = new    Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeAssistance.class);
            startActivity(goToLakeAssistance);

        }
    });
    imageButton8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View imageButton8) {
            Intent goToLakeOtherServices = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,   LakeOtherServices.class);
            startActivity(goToLakeOtherServices);

        }
    });

}public void onClick(View v) {
}

}
```

On the buttons in xml, I have

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

After trying the suggestion on here, my code now looks like this: But the app won't even run the first page. I took out the last bit of code as you suggested but when my onClick listener in android studio implemented, it adds the code right back.

```
public class LakeOptions extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.lake);

    Button imageButton5= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton5);
    Button imageButton6= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);
    Button imageButton7= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton7);
    Button imageButton8= (Button) findViewById(R.id.imageButton8);


   imageButton5.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent goToLakeFood = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeFood.class);
        startActivity(goToLakeFood);

    }
        });
    imageButton6.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v){
       Intent goToLakeHousing = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeHousing.class);
       startActivity(goToLakeHousing);

    }
       });
    imageButton7.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent goToLakeAssistance = new Intent(LakeOptions.this,LakeAssistance.class);
            startActivity(goToLakeAssistance);

        }
    });
    imageButton8.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent goToLakeOtherServices = new Intent(LakeOptions.this, LakeOtherServices.class);
            startActivity(goToLakeOtherServices);

        }
    });

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your XML file, you want to remove:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
```

since you're setting up the button handlers in the java code.

Also, you want to remove the last onClick function since you're not using it. (scroll to the bottom of your code)

And finally, replace the onClick handler signatures:

```
public void onClick(View imageButton[5-8])
```

with

```
public void onClick(View v)
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested RichS and the app won't even run the first activity. When I comment the function out it works. I will edit the new code above. Thank you.

Comment: Will android studio let you keep the function commented out?  I'm more familiar with Eclipse (I haven't used android studio).

Comment: When I comment it out then my onClickListener turns red, and is not implemented. it says something about making it an abstract class, and I tried that too with the same results

Comment: If LakeOptions is the activity you wish to launch, you need to specify it in the activity tag (set the android:name=com.helpfinder.app.LakeOptions).

Comment: I have done that. I have activity tags set for all activities. Do I need an intent-filter too?

Comment: I got it! I was using Button instead of ImageButton in my code. I also added this to my activity manifest                                       <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>                                     Thank you so much for your help Rich! you helped steer me in the right direction with the onClick advice! I do appreciate it!